# Text rendering issues on Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, safari, rendering

I have some text rendering issues.

I have multiple text fields and labels. All of these labels have a font size of 0.45rem and a horizontal padding of 0 and vertical padding of 1 px.

But unfortunately, it looks different on Safari. Chrome works fine, Opera works fine. But on Safari, the text goes into a second line. I think it may has something to do with font rendering, but I'm not really sure.
I made a screenshot of these, but I zoomed in to have a better look on it (it's too small).

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!